# Setting master tables primary key on child table as foreign key in java

Tags: hibernate, jpa, java-ee-6

I have 2 entity A and B and both r related via

**@OnetoMany(A -> B)** and **@ManyToOne (B -> A)** relationship and also both has 10 rows each.

Now What I want is to update the child table but the foreign key of the child table should be same means the parent table will not get updated. What shall I do....?

Let me give u my entities so that and controller part,

My Child Entity,

```
package com.org.pc.entity;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.*;


/**
 * The persistent class for the physical_allocation_detail database table.
 * 
 */
@Entity
@Table(name="physical_allocation_detail", schema="spc_cg")
@NamedQuery(name="PhysicalAllocationDetail.findAll", query="SELECT p FROM PhysicalAllocationDetail p")
public class PhysicalAllocationDetail implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name="BudgetUpload_GENERATOR",sequenceName="spc_cg.seq_budget_id",allocationSize=1,initialValue=1)
    @GeneratedValue(generator="BudgetUpload_GENERATOR",strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    @Column(name="physical_allocation_d_id")
    private Integer physicalAllocationDId;

    private double general;

    @Column(name="physical_target")
    private double physicalTarget;

    private double sc;

    @Column(name="scheme_component_id")
    private Integer schemeComponentId;

    private double st;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to PhysicalAllocationMaster
    @ManyToOne(cascade={CascadeType.ALL})
    @JoinColumn(name="physical_allocation_m_id", insertable = true, updatable = true, nullable=false)
    private PhysicalAllocationMaster physicalAllocationMaster;

    public PhysicalAllocationDetail() {
    }

    public Integer getPhysicalAllocationDId() {
        return this.physicalAllocationDId;
    }

    public void setPhysicalAllocationDId(Integer physicalAllocationDId) {
        this.physicalAllocationDId = physicalAllocationDId;
    }

    public double getGeneral() {
        return this.general;
    }

    public void setGeneral(double general) {
        this.general = general;
    }

    public double getPhysicalTarget() {
        return this.physicalTarget;
    }

    public void setPhysicalTarget(double physicalTarget) {
        this.physicalTarget = physicalTarget;
    }

    public double getSc() {
        return this.sc;
    }

    public void setSc(double sc) {
        this.sc = sc;
    }

    public Integer getSchemeComponentId() {
        return this.schemeComponentId;
    }

    public void setSchemeComponentId(Integer schemeComponentId) {
        this.schemeComponentId = schemeComponentId;
    }

    public double getSt() {
        return this.st;
    }

    public void setSt(double st) {
        this.st = st;
    }

    public PhysicalAllocationMaster getPhysicalAllocationMaster() {
        return this.physicalAllocationMaster;
    }

    public void setPhysicalAllocationMaster(PhysicalAllocationMaster physicalAllocationMaster) {
        this.physicalAllocationMaster = physicalAllocationMaster;
    }
}
```

My Master entity

```
package com.org.pc.entity;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.*;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;


/**
 * The persistent class for the physical_allocation_master database table.
 * 
 */
@Entity
@Table(name="physical_allocation_master", schema="spc_cg")
@NamedQuery(name="PhysicalAllocationMaster.findAll", query="SELECT p FROM PhysicalAllocationMaster p")
public class PhysicalAllocationMaster implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name="BudgetUpload_GENERATOR",sequenceName="spc_cg.seq_budget_id",allocationSize=1,initialValue=1)
    @GeneratedValue(generator="BudgetUpload_GENERATOR",strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    @Column(name="physical_allocation_m_id")
    private Integer physicalAllocationMId;

    @Column(name="allocation_entry_by")
    private String allocationEntryBy;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    @Column(name="date_of_entry")
    private Date dateOfEntry;

    @Column(name="is_approved")
    private Integer isApproved;

    @Column(name="location_id")
    private Integer locationId;

    @Column(name="location_type_id")
    private Integer locationTypeId;

    @Column(name="scheme_id")
    private Integer schemeId;

    @Column(name="year_id")
    private Integer yearId;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to PhysicalAllocationDetail
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="physicalAllocationMaster", cascade={CascadeType.ALL}, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<PhysicalAllocationDetail> physicalAllocationDetails;

    public PhysicalAllocationMaster() {
    }

    public Integer getPhysicalAllocationMId() {
        return this.physicalAllocationMId;
    }

    public void setPhysicalAllocationMId(Integer physicalAllocationMId) {
        this.physicalAllocationMId = physicalAllocationMId;
    }

    public String getAllocationEntryBy() {
        return this.allocationEntryBy;
    }

    public void setAllocationEntryBy(String allocationEntryBy) {
        this.allocationEntryBy = allocationEntryBy;
    }

    public Date getDateOfEntry() {
        return this.dateOfEntry;
    }

    public void setDateOfEntry(Date dateOfEntry) {
        this.dateOfEntry = dateOfEntry;
    }

    public Integer getIsApproved() {
        return this.isApproved;
    }

    public void setIsApproved(Integer isApproved) {
        this.isApproved = isApproved;
    }

    public Integer getLocationId() {
        return this.locationId;
    }

    public void setLocationId(Integer locationId) {
        this.locationId = locationId;
    }

    public Integer getLocationTypeId() {
        return this.locationTypeId;
    }

    public void setLocationTypeId(Integer locationTypeId) {
        this.locationTypeId = locationTypeId;
    }

    public Integer getSchemeId() {
        return this.schemeId;
    }

    public void setSchemeId(Integer schemeId) {
        this.schemeId = schemeId;
    }

    public Integer getYearId() {
        return this.yearId;
    }

    public void setYearId(Integer yearId) {
        this.yearId = yearId;
    }

    public Set<PhysicalAllocationDetail> getPhysicalAllocationDetails() {
        return this.physicalAllocationDetails;
    }

    public void setPhysicalAllocationDetails(Set<PhysicalAllocationDetail> physicalAllocationDetailSet) {
        this.physicalAllocationDetails = physicalAllocationDetailSet;
    }

    public PhysicalAllocationDetail addPhysicalAllocationDetail(PhysicalAllocationDetail physicalAllocationDetail) {
        getPhysicalAllocationDetails().add(physicalAllocationDetail);
        physicalAllocationDetail.setPhysicalAllocationMaster(this);

        return physicalAllocationDetail;
    }

    public PhysicalAllocationDetail removePhysicalAllocationDetail(PhysicalAllocationDetail physicalAllocationDetail) {
        getPhysicalAllocationDetails().remove(physicalAllocationDetail);
        physicalAllocationDetail.setPhysicalAllocationMaster(null);

        return physicalAllocationDetail;
    }

}
```

And My Controller part is,

```
List<PhysicalAllocationMaster> physicalAllocationMasterList=physicalAllocationMasterService.findByProperty("schemeId",schemeId,"yearId",yearId,"allocationEntryBy",allocEntryBy);

Integer masterListSize=physicalAllocationMasterList.size();
logger.info("Size of physicalAllocationMasterList =>"+masterListSize);

if(masterListSize!=0){
        PhysicalAllocationMaster physicalAllocationMaster = new PhysicalAllocationMaster();
        logger.info("Inside If------------"+masterListSize);
        for(int i = 0; i < masterListSize; i++){
         whysicalAllocationDetail physicalAllocationDetail = new PhysicalAllocationDetail();
        physicalAllocationDetail.setSchemeComponentId(schemeComponenet);

        if(general.length!=0 && general[i] != null && general[i].toString().trim().length() > 0){
            physicalAllocationDetail.setGeneral(Double.parseDouble(general[i]));
        }
        else{
            physicalAllocationDetail.setGeneral(0);
        }
        if(sc.length!=0 && sc[i] != null && sc[i].toString().trim().length() > 0){
            physicalAllocationDetail.setSc(Double.parseDouble(sc[i]));
        }else{
            physicalAllocationDetail.setSc(0);
        }
        if(st.length!=0 && st[i] != null && st[i].toString().trim().length() > 0){
            physicalAllocationDetail.setSt(Double.parseDouble(st[i]));
        }else{
            physicalAllocationDetail.setSt(0);
        }
        if(total.length!=0 && total[i] != null && total[i].toString().trim().length() > 0){
            physicalAllocationDetail.setPhysicalTarget(Double.parseDouble(total[i]));
        }else{
            physicalAllocationDetail.setPhysicalTarget(0);
        }

Integer physicalAllocationMID = physicalAllocationMasterList.get(i).getPhysicalAllocationMId();
List<PhysicalAllocationDetail> physicalAllocationDetailList = physicalAllocationDetailService.findByProperty("physicalAllocationMaster.physicalAllocationMId", physicalAllocationMID);

if(physicalAllocationDetailList.size()!=0){
    System.out.println("Scheme Component Id --- >"+schemeComponenet);
    List<PhysicalAllocationDetail> schemeComponentList=physicalAllocationDetailService.findByProperty("schemeComponentId", schemeComponenet);

Integer schemeComponentCount = schemeComponentList.size();

Integer physicalAllocationMId = schemeComponentList.get(0).getPhysicalAllocationMaster().getPhysicalAllocationMId();

if(schemeComponentCount!=0){
    Integer physicalAllocationDid = schemeComponentList.get(0).getPhysicalAllocationDId();
    physicalAllocationDetail.setPhysicalAllocationMaster(physicalAllocationMaster);
    physicalAllocationDetail.setPhysicalAllocationDId(physicalAllocationDid);
    physicalAllocationDetailService.merge(physicalAllocationDetail);
}
else{
    physicalAllocationMaster.setPhysicalAllocationMId(physicalAllocationMId);
    physicalAllocationDetail.setPhysicalAllocationMaster(physicalAllocationMaster);
    physicalAllocationDetailService.persist(physicalAllocationDetail);
   }
}else{
    System.out.println("<=================ERROR========================>");
    }
}}
```

Please help on this

Comment: did you try anything?

Comment: I tried to set the foreign key by setting the primary key directly and it always asks for a Master reference and then tried to do it by creating an object of Master entity but that is also not working as using PhysicalAllocationMaster master =new PhysicalAllocationMaster(); Always creates new object in master table so that is also of no use.

Comment: You have a bidirectional relationship which means both sides of relationship should know about each other

Comment: But For first entry I have to enter both master n detail and for then on wards master need not to get updated. Only depending on the situations multiple child needs to get updated or inserted... how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Remove `cascade={CascadeType.ALL}` in your `@ManyToOne` in `PhysicalAllocationDetail` class.